# Is it true that half of an aircraft wing's lift comes from upwash in front of the wing?

Tags: aerodynamics

Something I read lately stated that the lift on a wing is due to upwash in front and downwash behind, each contributing **equally** to the air momentum change that results in the lift. If this is true, I would like to understand the theory behind it. If it is Prandtl lifting line theory, please explain how it leads to the above conclusion.

Comment: Where did you read that? I would like to know the author's name so I can disregard anything else I happen to find that they wrote :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's some sort of accounting that leads to that conclusion (fluid dynamics is tricky), but the thing to remember is that once the wing has passed, it is the downflow of air that carries the momentum transferred to the wing as "lift". Upwash can only help by producing more downwash on the rebound.

Comment: This is a half-truth. The upwards force on the wing does not necessarily equate to downwards momentum of air after the wing passes, because the air can exert forces through pressure differentials without any air movement at all. Think of a floating balloon for example.

Comment: @AndrewSteane A floating balloon works on the difference in static pressure between the top of the envelope and the bottom. That's negligible for an aircraft wing.

Comment: Buoyancy is driven by gravity and the no shear condition of fluid statics. To generate lift above the buoyant force requires transferring momentum to the fluid and so creates downwash. I don't know what the question means by "upwash" I have never heard of this, but I agree with John Doty that all lift (assuming buoyancy is separated in the accounting) will accompany momentum downwash. How much of the momentum downwash is due to mass versus due to velocity is a matter of airfoil design. The less the mass and more the velocity, the more the induced power to fly.

Comment: @Poisson Aerohead A subsonic wing typically has upwash in front & downwash behind it. In 2-D flows, it's nearly symmetrical fore & aft. 3-D flows have much larger downwash behind them, of course.

Comment: Thank you all. I wish I could remember where I read that. It didn't make sense to me either.

Comment: @JohnDoty The pattern of air flow results in a large pressure difference between top and bottom of wing. Conservation of momentum here is partly via vertical acceleration of air, and partly via passing the force on from one part of the air to another.

Comment: @AndrewSteane The difference in pressure and the deflection of the flow are necessarily connected, otherwise momentum would not be conserved.

Comment: Part of the pressure difference is passed all the way to the ground.

Comment: @AndrewSteane That's significant only in ground effect. The transfer of momentum to the ground at higher altitudes occurs because the downwash can't flow downward forever: the ground ultimately deflects it, absorbing its momentum.

Comment: ok thanks for your responses: I admit my first comment was an overstatement.